# How to replace values values based on conditions from columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame (this is only a head of my real data, so I have more different names, not only az and nc).

```
 dat=structure(list(te = c("A", "B", "C","A","B","C",
                  "A", 
                  "B", "C","A", "B","C"), 
           rig = c("bad", "bad","bad","good", "goog","good",
                   
                   "ras", "ras","ras", "fas", "fas", "fas"), 
 index = c(1,2,5, 6, 4,  1, 0,4,2,1,4,5),value = 
 c(0.52,0.51,0.57, 0.49, 0.97,0.91,  0.43, 0.90, 
 0.98,0.80,0.70,0.11), name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L), levels = 
                                                                           
  c("az","az","az",  "az", "az","az","nc", "nc", "nc", 
  "nc","nc","nc"), class = "factor")), 
      row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to check for each name and rig columns, for instance

for az and bad,  we see the difference in values for A, B, and C is < 0.09, in this case replace  all corresponding (A,B, and C) in index by the maximum value (5 in this case).

for az and good   the difference in values for  B, and C is < 0.09, in this case replace  all corresponding (B and C) in index by the maximum value (4 in this case)

for nc and ras   the difference in values for  B and C is < 0.09, in this case replace  all corresponding (B and C) in index by the maximum value (4 in this case)

for nc and fas   the difference in values for  A, B and C is > 0.09, in this case leave as is

Desired output:

```
       te  rig index value name
    1   A  bad    5 0.52   az
    2   B  bad    5 0.51   az
    3   C  bad    5 0.57   az
    4   A good    6 0.49   az
    5   B goog    4 0.97   az
    6   C good    4 0.91   az
    7   A  ras    0 0.43   nc
    8   B  ras    4 0.90   nc
    9   C  ras    4 0.98   nc
   10  A  fas    1 0.80   nc
   11  B  fas    4 0.70   nc
   12  C  fas    5 0.11   nc
```

Comment: Which libraries are you using?

Comment: I added an answer that gets close to the indented output, but this question needs further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution is close to the expected result. What's not matching is due to the need for further clarification, but you might be able to adapt it.

- what if, in the same `rig` and `name` group the difference between A and B is less than 0.09 but between A and C is higher, which index should be returned? Should it be A index because not all differences are `<0.09`? I assumed that you only replace by `max(index)` if all differences are `<0.09`
- I guess the main issue I don't understand is, if you want to consider all the differences between one `te` and all the others (within `rig` and `name` grouping), or only between A and B, B and C (and not A an C). For instance, why is index in `6   C good    4 0.91   az` supposed to be 4 since the difference between C and A is higher than 0.09? I considered the differences between all possible combinations, you might need to adapt `diff` calculation in the script.

I slightly simplified the code for the example data, but I don't think it changes the data in anyway. Given your explanation I assumed that `goog` was a typo and replaced by `good`, but let me know otherwise.

```
# Example data
dat=data.frame(te = c("A", "B", "C","A","B","C",
                          "A", "B", "C","A", "B","C"), 
                   rig = c("bad", "bad","bad","good", "goog","good", 
                           "ras", "ras","ras", "fas", "fas", "fas"), 
                   index = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5), 
                   value = c(0.52, 0.51, 0.57, 0.49, 0.97, 0.91, 0.43, 0.90,
                             0.98,0.80,0.70,0.11), 
                   name = c("az", "az", "az", "az", "az", "az", "nc", "nc", "nc",
                            "nc","nc","nc"))

# Create a new data frame with all possible combinations within name an rig
new_dat <-  full_join(dat, dat, by = c('name', 'rig'))

head(new_dat)
  te.x rig index.x value.x name te.y index.y value.y
1    A bad       1    0.52   az    A       1    0.52
2    A bad       1    0.52   az    B       2    0.51
3    A bad       1    0.52   az    C       5    0.57
4    B bad       2    0.51   az    A       1    0.52
5    B bad       2    0.51   az    B       2    0.51
6    B bad       2    0.51   az    C       5    0.57

# Calculate the absolute difference between all pairs 
new_dat <- new_dat %>% 
          # filter(te.x < te.y) %>% # if needed removes duplicated combinations AB and BA and self intersection AA 
          mutate(pair = paste0(te.x, te.y), diff = abs(value.x - value.y))

    te.x rig index.x value.x name te.y index.y value.y pair diff
1    A bad       1    0.52   az    A       1    0.52   AA 0.00
2    A bad       1    0.52   az    B       2    0.51   AB 0.01
3    A bad       1    0.52   az    C       5    0.57   AC 0.05
4    B bad       2    0.51   az    A       1    0.52   BA 0.01
5    B bad       2    0.51   az    B       2    0.51   BB 0.00
6    B bad       2    0.51   az    C       5    0.57   BC 0.06

# retrieve the new index value 
# for comparison I created a new column called index_2
new_dat <- new_dat %>% 
           group_by(rig, name) %>% 
           mutate(index_2 = if(all(diff<0.09)) max(index.x, index.y) else index.x)

print(new_dat)
# A tibble: 12 × 11
# Groups:   rig, name [4]
   te.x  rig   index.x value.x name  te.y  index.y value.y pair    diff index_2
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A     bad         1    0.52 az    B           2    0.51 AB    0.0100       5
 2 A     bad         1    0.52 az    C           5    0.57 AC    0.0500       5
 3 B     bad         2    0.51 az    C           5    0.57 BC    0.0600       5
 4 A     good        6    0.49 az    B           4    0.97 AB    0.48         6
 5 A     good        6    0.49 az    C           1    0.91 AC    0.42         6
 6 B     good        4    0.97 az    C           1    0.91 BC    0.0600       4
 7 A     ras         0    0.43 nc    B           4    0.9  AB    0.47         0
 8 A     ras         0    0.43 nc    C           2    0.98 AC    0.55         0
 9 B     ras         4    0.9  nc    C           2    0.98 BC    0.0800       4
10 A     fas         1    0.8  nc    B           4    0.7  AB    0.100        1
11 A     fas         1    0.8  nc    C           5    0.11 AC    0.69         1
12 B     fas         4    0.7  nc    C           5    0.11 BC    0.59         4
```

Now you can select and rename columns as in your example.

```
new_dat<- new_dat %>% 
          select(te.x, rig, index_2, value.x, name) %>% 
          group_by(te.x, rig, name) %>% 
          distinct() %>% 
          rename(te = te.x, index = index_2, value = value.x)

print(new_dat) # as you can see some index values don't match your dataset, but I think this has to do with some confusion on the rules
# A tibble: 12 × 5
# Groups:   te, rig, name [12]
   te    rig   index value name 
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1 A     bad       5  0.52 az   
 2 B     bad       5  0.51 az   
 3 C     bad       5  0.57 az   
 4 A     good      6  0.49 az   
 5 B     good      4  0.97 az   
 6 C     good      1  0.91 az   
 7 A     ras       0  0.43 nc   
 8 B     ras       4  0.9  nc   
 9 C     ras       2  0.98 nc   
10 A     fas       1  0.8  nc   
11 B     fas       4  0.7  nc   
12 C     fas       5  0.11 nc
```